# Inactive word addin - reenable

Tags: installation, ms-word, vsto, add-in, word-2007

my problem is blocked VSTO word 2007 addin.
Once the addin breaks down, in non-debug mode, its unable to reenable it from word (set its status from inactive to active).
The only way to do this is to recompile the plugin.
I tried with LoadBehaviour=3 (word sets this value immediately into 0, after its run). There ae no Resiliency entries.

Its not caused by the exception on initialize (i have debugged it).

My suspect is, that word has cached plugin GUID somewhere, and doesnt allow to activate it. Is it possible, to remove all plugin informations, and reinstall it in word one more time?

Answer (score 0):

Once disabled (without debug attached) you have to re-enable it manually (Application Menu -> Word options -> Add-Ins -> select Disabled Add-ins in the menu at the bottom of the page -> enable your add-in).

You cannot re-enabled it programmatically because the add-in won't load and won't be able to execute any code at all.
When you recompile it in Visual Studio it probably gets deregistered and registered again, so you don't notice the problem.

Comment: No, the reason was Office 2007 doesnt works with plugins registered in HKLM.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811